# regex match 8 or 9 or 10 and this /10

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that matches `(8/10)` or `(9/10)` or `(10/10)` which is good but it also matches `(0/10)`.

I want the regex to only match `(8/10)` or `(9/10)` or `(10/10)`. Can someone please take a look at my regex and provide guidance?

```
\([8\-9,10].\/*.*\)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an alternation to match either 8, 9 or 10 followed by `/` and 10

The character class `[8\-9,10]` matches any of the listed chars, and as you escaped the `-` it could also match that.

```
\((?:[89]|10)/10\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5m4xC/1)